# Why is it recommended to put \relax before \ifmmode?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I've several times seen the recommendation to put a `\relax` before `\ifmmode` in a macro. I've tried searching for an explanation of this several times on this site, but hadn't been able to find one. [An answer by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197196/3627) to a different question I asked suddenly made things click, and I thought it'd be worthwhile to submit a question that might help others more effectively find the explanation of this.

Comment: It's a nice effort, but I think that there can't be said more than in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/ifmmode-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-inside-an-array-environment , which makes it a dupe IMHO...

Comment: Sure, I'm happy for the question be closed as a dupe, if it will still show up in searches and point others to the fuller answers. I considered suggesting that myself.

Answer (score 5):

In short, the explanation is that in several contexts:

```
\def\foo{\ifmmode alpha\else beta\fi}
...$\foo ...$ ...
```

it won't yet be visible that we're in math mode when `\foo` is invoked. But after `\relax`, then `\ifmmode` will then be able to see that we are in math mode.

Knowing the explanation, I was then able to find these further discussions of it on this site:

- [\ifmmode doesn't seem to work correctly inside an array environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27592/3627)
- [Unexpect differences between calling \ifmmode from within a command and outside a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123035/3627)

But these weren't easy to find until I did know the explanation.

For further discussion, one should consult Chapter 22 of The TeX Book, esp. p. 238.

Comment: note that `\relax` solves the problem of math mode at start of alignment but can cause problems in the non math case (as it breaks ligatures and kerning) and still fails in `\write` so a protected definition is usually preferable.