# Command created using math mode works in plain text but not if nested in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I've created some custom commands in my document so that if I change the variable, all occurcences can be changed easily. However, some of my command variables are contained in the math environment ($$). I use them both in plain text and inside equations. When I use them within an equation, I get `Missing $ inserted. [ $\mycommand]`, presumably due to the math mode value being nested inside math mode a second time. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\begin{document}



\newcommand{\mycommand}{$my_{command}$\xspace}


Here is my \mycommand working fine.

Here is my \mycommand not working in math mode:

 $\mycommand$


\end{document}
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Math macros should never include `$...$` and used in text should always be used inside `$...$`. That gives your document the proper semantics and eliminate the need for `\xspace` which should never be used.

Comment: @daleif That has been pointed out to me. However, even when not using math macros, if I create a plain text command, it doesn't respect the space I put after invoking it. Which means I'm left with having to add a space in the command. That, however, causes unwanted spaces when you follow the command with a comma or a period.

Comment: Then make a habit of always using `\foo{}`. Using `\xpsace` is a bad idea as it does not cover all corner cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For commands, that use math mode but should work in both, math mode and text mode, you should use `\ensuremath{…}` instead of `$…$`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{\ensuremath{my_{command}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

Here is my \mycommand working fine.

Here is my \mycommand working in math mode:

$\mycommand$

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: To separate form from content, definitions should be placed in the document preamble, i.e. before `\begin{document}`.

Note also: In your example `command` is the math product of `c`, `o`, `m` etc. If this is not intended, you should either use `\mathit{command}` for the single variable `command` or either `\mathrm{command}` or `\text{command}` (needs package `amsmath`) for the text `command`.

However, I would recommend to use something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{\mathit{my}_{\mathrm{command}}}

\begin{document}

Here is my $\mycommand$ working fine.

Here is my $\mycommand$ working in math mode:

\[
  \mycommand
\]

\end{document}
```

with explicitly switching to math mode for math material. Or:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{my\textsubscript{command}\xspace}

\begin{document}

Here is my \mycommand working fine.

Here is my \mycommand working in math mode:

\[
  \text{\mycommand}
\]

\end{document}
```

if the command is not intended to be math but text.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to fix my problem!

I understand, but in my document, it makes sense to me to declare the command when I first refer to the variable, because that's where I'll be looking to make changes if any. But generally I agree that it is much better form.

Right, I'll actually try for those variables that just have a subscript or superscript, thank you for the suggestion. But some of my variables are greek letters, and those I only seem to be able to invoke in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{}{\relax\ifmmode my_{command} \else $my_{command}$\xspace \fi}
\begin{document}
Here is my \mycommand working fine.

Here is my $\mycommand$ working fine.

Here is my \mycommand not working in math mode:

Here is my $\mycommand$ not working in math mode:
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you!

Comment: `\relax\ifmmode` is safer, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197198/82917

Comment: @Clara `\mycommand` should probably be robust (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/ifmmode-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-inside-an-array-environment)). I think if you declare macro as `\NewDocumentCommand...` it should be ok as it creates robust macros by default.

Comment: @campa  I have added `\relax`.

Comment: @Celdor I have changed it to be robust.

Comment: This is essentially reinventing `\ensuremath`.